# how to convert URL-encoded to json

Tags: javascript, json, url, decode

I'm getting location data through the following url: “%7B%22distance%22%3A1000000%2C%22country%22%3A%22BR%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22S%E3o%20Paulo%22%2C% 22latitude%22%3A-23.6283%2C%22longitude%22%3A-46.6409%2C%22region_code%22%3A%22SP%22%7D” . I need to transform this url into a json file but the javascript decode function returns URI Malformed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5j8U.png)

Comment: unescape() will probably do it for you

Comment: Looks like you have a whitespace in your string `2%2C% 22latitude` Is that actually in the string?

Comment: window.unescape('%7B%22distance%22%3A1000000%2C%22country%22%3A%22BR%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22S%E3o%20Paulo%22%2C% 22latitude%22%3A-23.6283%2C%22longitude%22%3A-46.6409%2C%22region_code%22%3A%22SP%22%7D')
23:13:34.261 '{"distance":1000000,"country":"BR","city":"São Paulo",% 22latitude":-23.6283,"longitude":-46.6409,"region_code":"SP"}'

Comment: decodeURI does not like `%E3`

Comment: By removing the space that @epascarello mentioned, and using **JSON.parse(unescape(Str))**, it will parse to JSON correctly.

Comment: unescape worked but was deprecated. the space only occurs in the post in the original string it doesn't have. decodeURI and decodeURIComponent don't work @epascarello,

Comment: It does not like the windows encoding of ã

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.